# CSS - positioning a horizontal line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a horizontal line on a section for a site I'm building and can't get it in the correct place. This is a Photoshop version of how it should look -
[image: PSD version]

This is my coded version  - 
[image: Coded version]

I'm using the *hr* tag to create it as this seems the most straightforward way - here's the code -

```css
hr {

    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gumby/2.6.4/css/gumby.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="welcome">
       <div class="container"> 
            <div class="row">
                <div class="twelve columns">
                <h4>WELCOME TO FEATURE MEDIA</h4>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel ex nisl. Vestibulum vitae ultricies nisl. Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor. Suspendisse nec venenatis nisi. Phasellus sodales viverra ante quis efficitur. Pellentesque quis orci mi. Phasellus tempus, sapien ut luctus pellentesque, lacus risus accumsan lorem, in porta urna tellus ac nibh. Nunc varius elit non diam vehicula aliquet. In eget urna id orci molestie pulvinar. Integer quis risus eu erat iaculis aliquet ut at eros. Etiam feugiat, ante vel molestie finibus, lacus urna pharetra leo, ut lobortis massa lectus quis lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus turpis sagittis sapien vulputate sagittis. Nunc ac velit sollicitudin, consequat arcu ac, tincidunt risus.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
                <hr>
            <div class="row"> 
                <div class="four columns"> 
                    <div id="video">      
                        <h3>VIDEO</h3>
                        <img src="images/VIDEO.jpg" alt="Video" style="width:300px;height:150px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="four columns"> 
                    <div id="blog">   
                        <h3>BLOG</h3>
                        <img src="images/blog.jpg" alt="blog" style="width:300px;height:150px;">
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <div class="four columns"> 
                    <div id="faq"> 
                        <h3>FAQ</h3>
                        <img src="images/faq.jpg" alt="FAQ" style="width:300px;height:150px;">
                    </div>   
                </div><hr>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Quite difficult to debug when the posted code doesn't reproduce the same output your image shows....

Comment: I believe he's using gumby css framework https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gumby/2.6.4/css/gumby.min.css based off of the `class="four columns"` still can not get it to completely replicate the look of the picture though.

Comment: @LGSon I'm using skeleton grid for the site, is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, I was. It is important to know to be able to debug properly. Posted an answer, will that work?

Comment: @LGSon No, it hasn't changed anything re the positioning. I need it to be centred like the PSD version.

Comment: Well, since your posted code I use in my answer center it, there must be something missing, so you need to post a code snippet that actually reproduce the issue you encounter.

Comment: @LGSon I've looked at your code snippet and it looks exactly like my coded version, it doesn't look like the PSD version.

Comment: Now it does.. :)

Comment: @LGSon This looks great - thanks. One last thing - how do I adjust the color of the line? I need it to be light grey/grey.

Comment: @LGSon No worries. Done.

Comment: Great ...and the answer is (and would been) updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hr` is already given a style in the framework, so if you give it a class like this, it will override the default.

The major reason why it is not exactly positioned vertically between the text and image part, is that the text row and image row has not the same top/bottom margin/padding, so I increased the margin-top/bottom a little, and the second `hr`, the one after the images, were placed within the `row`, so I moved it outside.

To get it exact in between, you have elaborate with the row's padding/margin.

Stack snippet

```css
hr.hr250center {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2.5em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;             /*  here you set color  */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="welcome">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="twelve columns">
        <h4>WELCOME TO FEATURE MEDIA</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel ex nisl. Vestibulum vitae ultricies nisl. Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque
          facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor. Suspendisse nec venenatis nisi. Phasellus sodales viverra ante quis efficitur. Pellentesque quis orci mi. Phasellus tempus, sapien ut luctus pellentesque, lacus risus accumsan lorem, in porta urna tellus
          ac nibh. Nunc varius elit non diam vehicula aliquet. In eget urna id orci molestie pulvinar. Integer quis risus eu erat iaculis aliquet ut at eros. Etiam feugiat, ante vel molestie finibus, lacus urna pharetra leo, ut lobortis massa lectus quis
          lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus turpis sagittis sapien vulputate sagittis. Nunc ac velit sollicitudin, consequat arcu ac, tincidunt risus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <hr class="hr250center">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="four columns">
        <div id="video">
          <h3>VIDEO</h3>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00" alt="Video" style="width:300px;height:150px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="four columns">
        <div id="blog">
          <h3>BLOG</h3>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00" alt="blog" style="width:300px;height:150px;">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="four columns">
        <div id="faq">
          <h3>FAQ</h3>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100/f00" alt="FAQ" style="width:300px;height:150px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="hr250center">
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option: 'padding-top' or 'padding-bottom'

```
<section id="welcome">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 50px;">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                <h4>WELCOME TO FEATURE MEDIA</h4>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec vel ex nisl. Vestibulum vitae ultricies nisl. Praesent sodales, leo at pellentesque pellentesque, nunc erat dapibus nunc, ut congue libero lorem in orci. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque facilisis mauris in vestibulum tempor. Suspendisse nec venenatis nisi. Phasellus sodales viverra ante quis efficitur. Pellentesque quis orci mi. Phasellus tempus, sapien ut luctus pellentesque, lacus risus accumsan lorem, in porta urna tellus ac nibh. Nunc varius elit non diam vehicula aliquet. In eget urna id orci molestie pulvinar. Integer quis risus eu erat iaculis aliquet ut at eros. Etiam feugiat, ante vel molestie finibus, lacus urna pharetra leo, ut lobortis massa lectus quis lorem. Vestibulum rhoncus turpis sagittis sapien vulputate sagittis. Nunc ac velit sollicitudin, consequat arcu ac, tincidunt risus.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
            <div class="four columns">
                <div id="video">
                    <h3>VIDEO</h3>
                    <img src="images/VIDEO.jpg" alt="Video" style="width:300px;height:150px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                <div id="blog">
                    <h3>BLOG</h3>
                    <img src="images/blog.jpg" alt="blog" style="width:300px;height:150px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                <div id="faq">
                    <h3>FAQ</h3>
                    <img src="images/faq.jpg" alt="FAQ" style="width:300px;height:150px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <hr>
    </div>
</section>
```